# How can I use a VPN to access a Russian website that is banned in the EU?

Tags: networking, vpn, unix, openvpn, http

I am a lover of a Russian website. And recently the EU put a ban on it. They say it is because of the Ukraine war. So I registered a Russian [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) and installed an [OpenVPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN) server on it (using [a popular script](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install) that automates the process). The DNS server that I selected was `1.1.1.1`, I thought it was smart, so I selected UDP on port 443.

However, when I connect to it as an OpenVPN-client from my apartment in the EU, it appears that the content is still blocked. My friend has another VPN. This is [NordVPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NordVPN), and she may view the content without problems on her Mac. I am using a machine with [Debian 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_11_(Bullseye)) (Bullseye) and without [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).

To narrow down the problem, I have used the terminal browser called [w3m](https://w3m.sourceforge.net) while being logged in by SSH on the VPS, and I can view the content that way. I can see that by using the standard test of `dnsleaktest.com`, I have a DNS-leak with the default configuration.

I hope the above information, for someone who's in the know, might be all that is needed to infer what's the matter.

I'm not exactly sure how the Russian censorship was technically implemented. So, that implicitly defines the question: If I can understand how the censorship is implemented, I hope to learn how to configure my server and client to get access.

Comment: have you tried the DNS 8.8.8.8 ? it's the Google DNS server~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. I installed the package `openresolv` that is available for Debian (the ArchWiki has more information about [DNS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/OpenVPN#DNS)).
2. The second thing I did was to insert the following three lines into the `ovpn-file` before the `<ca>-tag`:

   ```
   script-security 2
   up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
   down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
   ```

And Bob's your uncle!

So I guess the EU is blocking these sites by the use of DNS servers. I will wait to accept an answer for the question for anyone else who has more extensive knowledge, for a while.

Comment: Is the "insert the following **two** lines" when you have three lines a typo?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks.